# How do I record Purchased Annual Leave?

Tags: double-entry, bookkeeping

My employer has an arrangement where one can "purchase" annual leave. This works by giving you say 40 hours of additional annual leave to take whenever you like, and then over the course of a year, there is a small deduction to every paycheque issued.

So for example if your hourly rate was $10, then purchasing 40 hours of annual leave (worth $400) would mean every week, you'd have a deduction of ~$7.69 (400/52).

I'm not so sure how to account for this, though. My thinking was that the point at which the annual leave is purchased there needs to be a Credit to a liability account, but I'm not sure what account needs to be Debited.

As for every pay period, I've been Debiting the liability account with the deduction to reduce its balance. It balances out the rest of the transaction for the wages/net pay.

What would be the best way to account for this?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few ways to do this. You could just treat it like a recurring expense on your paycheck entry. That's the simplest way, but doesn't capture the full "expense" upfront if you are obligated to pay the full deduction even if you quit.

Or you could debit the full expense upfront, credit a liability, and add a credit to the liability on each paycheck. That accounts for the full expense upfront and you just "pay it off" over each paycheck.

Answer (score 0):

> My thinking was that the point at which the annual leave is purchased there needs to be a Credit to a liability account, but I'm not sure what account needs to be Debited.

If I understand correctly,
in effect you are on unpaid leave,
but you are given an advance on salary.
So the corresponding debit would be
the portion of the paycheck you get as an advance
during the period when you are on leave.

For simplicity and uniformity,
you could just debit (reimburse) your salary income account.
This way you can handle your paycheck the way you usually would,
and record the leave as a separate transaction.